# Should I divide my time series data into frames/chunks for binary classification?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, classification, waveform

I am trying to classify between earthquake and non-earthquake waveforms(Binary classification). My data consists of 480,000 rows and 3 features. Each consecutive 6000 rows corresponds to a waveform for an earthquake or non-earthquake event. I have a total of 40 such events. So my question is that should I divide my dataset into 40 frames, each of 6000 rows before training my model or should I train the model treating each row as a different entity?

Comment: You say you have 480,000 rows, but 40 events of 6,000 rows each, what is the other half of the data? You could treat the events as separate samples and see if you can learn a classifier that can predict whether or not an event is an earthquake, this would be time series classification. Since you have 3 features, it would be multivariate time series classification.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use domain knowledge to answer this question. Suppose you want to predict if the upcoming waveform is an earthquake or not. What is the input -- 3 features or a frame?

Most of the ML algorithms operate under the assumption that the training set and the test set have i.i.d. samples -- can you assume it here? If yes, how do you structure the data? If you need to reshape it, extract new features, etc -- it is up to you, your usage of the domain knowledge. If you don't have the i.i.d. samples, find the method that mitigates it -- maybe it is time series.